# My PC slows down when downloading

Tags: networking, windows-10, hard-drive, audio, ssd

I have a very strange issue, my PC seems to slow down when I get to download something fast. The mouse moves slow and jumping and if I'm listening or watching something, the audio struggles a lot. I attach a video where you can listen the music: https://streamable.com/ngzgt (the volume is a bit soft, but I think you can hear it).

It does not matter if the download goes to the SSD or the HD.

My pc is:

- Windows 10
- CPU Intel 4790
- MSI Z97 Gaming 5
- G.Skill TridentX DDR3 1600 PC3-12800 16GB 2x8GB CL7
- Kingston SSDNow V300 240GB
- HD 1TB (Seagate)
- Tacens Valeo V 700W 80 Plus Silver Modular
- My network adapter is this one (  Intel 6300AGN ): https://www.amazon.es/dp/B079RBN14S/ref=pe_3310721_189395781_TE_SCE_dp_1
- nVidia 2070 Super

Comment: You might be demanding too much from the Operating System. If you want to use Torrent Downloaders at their Full Speed (Download Rate), then just leave them overnight and do not demand any kind of User Interaction with them. Otherwise, even with 16 Giga-Bytes of Random Access Memory, this might be the Usual Performance of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System.

Comment: If your mouse and possibly your audio solution (speakers/headphones) are Bluetooth or some other version of 2.4GHz wireless, then this could be RF interference, not a system slowdown.

Strong enough RF interference from Wi-Fi can also create noise in analog audio circuits via electromagnet induction.

Consider buying an antenna rig that keeps your Wi-Fi antennas well away from the rest of your system. Also make sure to keep your PC case/enclosure/shielding fully closed. Don't even leave any card slot spaces open; put the blank slot-fillers back in place.

Comment: You didn't mention CPU at all. Wi-Fi downloads are slow, try using Ethernet. I download multiple stuff on my computer while i'm using it with a 7-year old 8GB RAM computer with no issues.

Comment: I added the CPU info. It's not that the download is slow, in fact it is quite fast. It's the computer the one which struggles to compute at the same time that is downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: change the Energy Mode of Windows 10 from "high performance" to "Balanced". Somehow the "high performance" mode was only using one core of the CPU.